# Display popup like google calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a calendar .I have used fullcalendar.js to implement this.Now i want to display a popup like google calendar.I have used the code given below.Here the popup dialog will appear only in the center.I want to show it in the position of clicked event.Please give me a solution.

```
    var calendar = $('#datepicker');
calendar.fullCalendar
({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    defaultEventMinutes: 60,
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) 
    {
    if(eventEdit)
    {
       $('.ui-dialog').hide();
       eventEdit = false;
    }
    if(jsEvent.title == undefined)
    {
        var createEvent = prompt('Event Title:','',{
        buttons: {
            Ok: true,
            Cancel: false
        }
       });
    }
    else
    {
        var createEvent = prompt('Event Title:', jsEvent.title, {
            buttons: 
            {
                Ok: true,
                Cancel: false
            }
           });
    }
    if (createEvent)
    {
      jsEvent.title = createEvent;
      calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', { title: jsEvent.title, start: date, allDay: false, editable: true}, true );   
    }      
    eventEdit = true;
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) 
    {
    if(eventEdit)
    {
       $('.ui-dialog').hide();
       eventEdit = false;
    }
    var timing = $('.fc-event-time').html();
    var dialog = $('<p class="event" align="justify">Event:'+calEvent.title+'<br/>Timing:'+timing+'</p>').dialog
    ({
        buttons: 
        {
           "Edit Event": function()
             {               
                   dialog.dialog('close');
                   var editEvent = prompt('Event Title:', calEvent.title, {
                    buttons: 
                    {
                        Ok: true,
                        Cancel: false
                    }
                   });
                  if (editEvent)
                  {
                      calEvent.title = editEvent;
                      calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent',calEvent);
                  }
              },
          "Delete Event":  function() 
                    {
         calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
         dialog.dialog('close');
                    }
        }
    }); 
    eventEdit = true;
    },
    header: 
    {
        left: "prev,next today",
        center: "title",
        right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    }
});
```

Comment: can you make fiddle or provide css...

Comment: I have used the fullcalendar.css for this.                        Please look in to the given link http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.css